# CSS hover transform on different elements doesnt work

Tags: jquery, css

I have a problem with moving elements on hover. Here is the HTML

```
<nav class="user-navbar">
    <ul>
        <li>My Stories</li>
        <li>Following</li>
        <li>Hot Stuff<sup class="fa fa-circle"></sup></li>
        <li>Everyone</li>
        <li>Categories<i class="fa fa-sort-desc"></i></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="pointer"></div>
</nav>
```

Here is what i tied to do

```
.user-navbar li:nth-child(2):hover #pointer {
    transform: translateX(100px);
}
```

I want my #pointer element to move when hovering over 2nd li element. This doesnt work. Please tell me how can i solve this with CSS or maybe with jQuery. Thanks!!

Comment: Your selector  won't work because `#pointer` is not a descendant of `li`

Comment: There is no parent selector In CSS yet :/

Comment: You can't address `#pointer` as a descendent or sibling of an `li`. You'll need to either address by some state of `ul` (e.g., `ul:hover`) or by using javascript to set a class on the `#pointer` element.

Comment: If a list is not required, move your elements into  div and use the general sibling selector https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors `~`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no parent selector in CSS3, so you can't select an element not inside the target elements parent.
You have a few options:

1. Use JavaScript
2. Use the ever present `checkbox` hack

I'll explain both.

### Use JavaScript:

This is quite easy to do in JS, here is a version in jQuery:

```js
$(function(){
  $(".user-navbar li:nth-child(2)").hover(function(){
    $("#pointer").addClass("move");
    },function(){
    $("#pointer").removeClass("move");
    });
  });
```

```css
 #pointer.move {
      transform: translateX(100px);
   }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="user-navbar">
            <ul>
                <li>My Stories</li>
                <li>Following</li>
                <li>Hot Stuff<sup class="fa fa-circle"></sup></li>
                <li>Everyone</li>
                <li>Categories<i class="fa fa-sort-desc"></i></li>
            </ul>
            <div id="pointer">Trararara</div>
        </nav>
```

However, that requires you to use jQuery. If you are the sort of person, like me, who dislikes using jQuery, you are going to be looking for a pure JS version

```js
var p = document.getElementById("pointer");
var secondLI = document.querySelectorAll(".user-navbar li")[1];
secondLI.onmouseover = function(){
  p.classList.add("move");
}
secondLI.onmouseout = function(){
  p.classList.remove("move");
}
```

```css
#pointer.move {
      transform: translateX(100px);
   }
```

```html
<nav class="user-navbar">
            <ul>
                <li>My Stories</li>
                <li>Following</li>
                <li>Hot Stuff<sup class="fa fa-circle"></sup></li>
                <li>Everyone</li>
                <li>Categories<i class="fa fa-sort-desc"></i></li>
            </ul>
            <div id="pointer">Trararara</div>
        </nav>
```

That's It!

### Use the ever present `checkbox` hack:

The `checkbox` hack is a messy way to do many things in CSS, in this case, select a parent.
So, let's start. 
First of all, we take your nice HTML structure like this, and add in a check-box and label:

```
<nav class="user-navbar">
<input type="checkbox" id="hoverHack" name="hoverHack" style="position:fixed;left:-100000px;">
            <ul>
                <li>My Stories</li>
                <li><label for="hoverHack">Following</label></li>
                <li>Hot Stuff<sup class="fa fa-circle"></sup></li>
                <li>Everyone</li>
                <li>Categories<i class="fa fa-sort-desc"></i></li>
            </ul>
            <div id="pointer"></div>
        </nav>
```

The concept is this, you place the checkbox in the html structure above the elements you are trying to select, then hide it with positioning(who wants a random checkbox?). You then place a label for the check box in the element you want to hover over. any event used on the label, is also used on the checkbox. We have the HTML, so all we need is a little CSS magic:

```
#hoverHack:hover ~ #pointer {
      transform: translateX(100px);
   }
```

TADA!!!

```css
#hoverHack:hover ~ #pointer {
          transform: translateX(100px);
       }
```

```html
<nav class="user-navbar">
    <input type="checkbox" id="hoverHack" name="hoverHack" style="position:fixed;left:-100000px;">
                <ul>
                    <li>My Stories</li>
                    <li><label for="hoverHack">Following</label></li>
                    <li>Hot Stuff<sup class="fa fa-circle"></sup></li>
                    <li>Everyone</li>
                    <li>Categories<i class="fa fa-sort-desc"></i></li>
                </ul>
                <div id="pointer">Taralala</div>
            </nav>
```

So, with a little tweak to the HTML structure, you *can* select elements not in the target elements parent, just with CSS. Enjoy!

Comment: Thank you for great answer. Didnt about about this fancy checkbox hack!

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery to achieve your desired result.

```
$('.user-navbar li:nth-child(2)').hover(function() {
        $(this).closest('nav').find('#pointer').css('transform', 'translateX(100px)');  
})
```

The above event listener traverses the parent entities and applies a style to matching child element.

http://jsfiddle.net/x75pzywk/

Additionally, if you need to 'toggle' the translate:

```
$('.user-navbar li:nth-child(2)').hover(function() {
        $(this).closest('nav').find('#pointer').toggleClass('active');  
})
```

CSS

```
#pointer.active {
    transform: translateX(100px);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hnaxrtf2/2/

Note: The above example assumes that the elements provided exists in a heirachry.

Answer (score 0):

This is no way that I know of to do this in pure CSS. Use the jQuery library to do this with a `mouseover` listener on your item:

```
$(".user-navbar li:nth-child(2)").on('mouseover', function() {
  $("#pointer").css({
    transform: 'translateX(100px)'
  });
});
```

and then if you want it to move back on `mouseleave`

```
$(".user-navbar li:nth-child(2)").on('mouseleave', function() {
  $("#pointer").css({
    transform: 'translateX(0px)'
  });
});
```